# Play sbt scala to generate scala doc

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

I research and tried many things and I can not get it to generate scaladoc. I ran sbt clean doc and play clean doc and nothing happened, I added some code in the build. Scala and nothing happen. Can someone help to see what am I missing.

Below is the piece of code generate scaladoc from build.scala

```
object Tasks { 
val generateAPIDocsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("app-doc") <<= (fullClasspath in Test, compilers, streams) map { 
  (classpath, cs, s) =>         
    //IO.delete(file("documentation/api"))
    // Scaladoc
  println(" class path : " + classpath)
    val sourceFiles = 
          (file("app/*") ** "*.scala").get ++ 
          (file("test") ** "*.scala").get ++ 
          (file("target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/views/html") ** "*.scala").get
    new Scaladoc(10, cs.scalac)(appName + " " + appVersion + " Scala API", sourceFiles, classpath.map(_.data), file("documentation/api/scala"), Nil, s.log)

    println(" class path : " + classpath)
   }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Did you get any error messages? If so, please add them here!

Comment: No I did not get any error..
pauldao@pauls-mbp:~/InCrowdAPI% sbt clean doc

[info] Updating {file:/Users/pauldao/InCrowdAPI/project/project/}default-b4ec36...
nfo] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pauldao/InCrowdAPI/project
[info] Set current project to InCrowdAPI (in build file:/Users/pauldao/InCrowdAPI/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 30, 2014 8:57:03 AM
[info] Updating {file:/Users/pauldao/InCrowdAPI/}InCrowdAPI...
[info] Done updating.                                                        
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 30, 2014 8:57:05 AM

Comment: does this directory `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/views/html` exist after you run `doc` in SBT? Are you running the `doc` command from the root project? For me by default docs go to somewhere here `<path-to-repo>/<project>/target/scala-2.10/api`. Try to find html files in your repo dir: `find . -name "*.html`

Comment: No it did not create that directory..

Comment: What's the version of SBT? Could you run `sbt about` in the project's main directory? Could you show `build.sbt` and other files from `project` directory (`*.sbt` and `*.scala`)?